# Date set in an entry is outputting 4 hours behind the date set

Tags: php, date, server, server-migration

One of the expressionengine sites I run is having a strange but that I suspect is something to with the recent server move we just did.

In an entry the user can set a start/finish time of an event and this will then display on the site for people to see, the code I'm using to display the date is this;

```
                    <?php
                    //date format
                      $start_date       =   '{start_date}';
                      $end_date     =   '{end_date}';
                        $strtD  = date('D j', $start_date);
                        $strtM  = date('M', $start_date);
                        $endD   = date('D j', $end_date);
                        $endM   = date('M', $end_date);

                        if ($strtD == $endD && $strtM == $endM) {
                            echo $strtD .' '. $strtM;
                        } else if ($strtM == $endM) {
                            echo $strtD .' - '. $endD .' '.$endM;   
                        } else {
                            echo $strtD .' '. $strtM .' - '. $endD .' '.$endM ; 
                        }

                    ?>
```

The issue thats happening is when the start and finish date is set, for example to 11/04/2015 00:00 on the output of the post it display the 10th of april instead of the 11th. I tried upping the time to 01:00 and still no luck and i tried 02:00 and 03:00 which didn't work either but when i did 04:00 it then put the outputted date to 11th April.

This makes me think it's some issue with timezone settings, which I have checked as deep as I can think of, I have set the server time to GMT and specified this in the EE setting, I'm at a bit of a lost end now as I have tried everything I can think of, does anyone have any suggestions with what the issue could be/how it can be fixed?

Thanks in advance, Harry.

Comment: One would assume you restarted apache/nginx after you changed timezone settings?

Comment: No, I didn't. I just restarted the cron, do you think that would be the issue?

Comment: By server time do you mean you changed the timezone in php.ini? If you're running apache+php5, you need to set it in your php.ini AND restart apache with a command like "apachectl restart" or "sudo service apache2 restart"